# Vba modify current cell content with a function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to access to the current cell and modify something on it. Not the ActiveCell (it works only if there is no entry in the function), but the cell in which the equation is entering (in this case : `=myFunction(A1)` for example).

Here the code :

```
Public Function myFunction(anotherCell As String) As String
    'Do something with anotherCell
    myFunction = "something"
    'Change interior cell color
    'Add hyperlink
End Function
```

I want to add a hyperlink on this specific cell and modify its inner color (not the text color). I know how to do it on a defined cell by its position, but not on the cell where the string "something" will be written.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected result?

Comment: Function called from the worksheet cannot change the format or value of another cell, nor can it change the format of the cell calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Scott for your answer.
So as you said : **Function called from the worksheet cannot change the format or value of another cell, nor can it change the format of the cell calling it.**
And it makes sense. I will search another way to do my job.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to select the range in a object before and to call the function with it ?

Dim anotherCell as range
Set anotherCell = range("A1").select 'For example

' and you call your function (you have to declare it before in a specific 'functions' module for example)
myFunction(anotherCell)

Comment: 1.You cannot select another cell from a Function called from the worksheet. 2. Using `.Select` is almost never the answer to problems, One should avoid `.Select` and simply reference the cell in the call.  `.Select` only slows down the code.